# Is it possible to stream video to raspberry pi from a webcam?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, webcam-capture

I am building a self driving car model using python(tensorflow). The architecture design of my project looks like the following. The CNN code will be in the raspberry pi, which is connected to a radio controller using wires from it's GPIO pins to send motion signals. The pi then controls the car. To "see" what's around it, the car uses a webcam that is mounted at the front center(this is the puzzle), which I wanted to stream the video to the pi; then the pi will use it's trained model(brain) to decide whether or not to move forward, make a left turn, a right turn and so on. The pi and rc radio controller are not mounted on the car, and I want them to remain that way for a reason. The car has the webcam and that is it. I am considering replacing the webcam with an android phone due to lack of alternatives, but I would hate to do that. If you would like more explanation on the structure of my project, please comment down there.

My question is how can I stream the video to my pi in real time?

Comment: Use a second raspberry pi on the car? Cheaper than a phone, and no matter what, you need some sort of computer to encode the video stream form car to computer.

Comment: @szatmary, I was thinking that as well. I just was gonna use one of my test phones to save money. But looks like that is the only solution. Thanks so much.